# Oracle Db: Grant select doesn't show up in dba_sys_privs

Tags: oracle

In Oracle, I granted select on a table to a user by giving the following command:

```
GRANT SELECT ON DEPT TO HOMERSIMPSON;
```

Once I granted a select on the dept table to homersimpson, I queried the dba_sys_privs, there's no record of the privilege granted. I used the following query:

```
Select * from dba_sys_privs where grantee = 'HOMERSIMPSON';
```

[image]

Why is the privilege not reported on this table?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are granting a SELECT *on a specific table*.  That's not a system priv.  It is an *object* prv.  Try looking at [DBA_TAB_PRIVS.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/DBA_TAB_PRIVS.html#GUID-4AC57A96-FF55-4788-9301-AFED23AE3934)