# Oracle: Granting Select ANY Table doesn't show up in dba_tab_privs

Tags: oracle

I have an issue where I (as sysdba) granted a privilege to perform a select on any table to a user. I used the following query:

```
GRANT SELECT ANY TABLE TO BARTSIMPSON
```

I get the message that grant succeeded. But I don't see a record of this privilege in the dba_tab_privs. Why? Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Just the opposite of what you asked [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69328931/oracle-db-grant-select-doesnt-show-up-in-dba-sys-privs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking in the wrong view. `dba_tab_privs` shows table privileges. `select any table` is a **system** privilege. You should look for it in `dba_sys_privs`.